# Not able to get product Identifiers from iTunes Connect in app purchase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, plist, app-store-connect

iam using In App purchase in my project.Currently things are working purchase are happening from sandbox.But i found one issue regarding the product identifiers.Now iam hard coding the product identifier like below. Am storing the product identifier in a plist (ProductId.plist)manually (please refer image)

```
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"

@implementation RageIAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ProductId" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSArray * contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        NSLog(@"content aray:%@",contentArray);
        NSSet * productIdentifiers= [NSSet setWithArray:contentArray];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

//CODE FROM RAY WENDERLICH IN APP PURCHASE TUTTORIAL

[image: ProductId.PLIST]

Problem is now am not able to take the product identifiers dynamically from the iTunes Store. So how can i get Product id from itunes store instead of hard coding in plist???
please help

Answer (score 2):

You can't get those identifiers from the AppStore!. If you really need to deliver those product identifiers dynamically, you should put a file with the list of identifiers in a visible server.

Please read the section [Feature Delivery in Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW13). You should use the "Server Product Model".

## Edit post-iOS 7:

The old link that I wrote is outdated. [The current doc is more explicit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW6)

Answer (score 2):

You can do following to get product data.

```
 NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.****.******"];
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest start];
```

This delegate will get call which will get product information you required

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

Comment: This method is only work for fetching info of an existing product id, not for fetching product ids from iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get product ids from AppStore IN APP,
but you can generate plist of product ids automatically.

Here's steps:

1. Fetch `metadata.xml` by using [transporter](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/TransporterQuickStartUserGuide/pdf):

   ```
   iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata \
   -u [username] \
   -p [password] \
   -vendor_id [vendor id] \
   -subitemtype InAppPurchase \
   -destination [local destination]
   ```
2. Transform `metadata.xml` into `product_ids.plist`:

   ```
   # /usr/bin/sh
   # usage: [this script] [path/to/metadata.xml] > [path/to/product_ids.plist]

   echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
   echo '<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"'
   echo ' "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">'
   echo '<plist version="1.0">'
   echo '<array>'

   sed -n 's/.*<product_id>\(.*\)<.*/    \<string\>\1\<\/string\>/p' $1

   echo '</array>'
   echo '</plist>'
   ```

You can integrate those shell script into your production deploy script, or you can write your own script base on this concept.